# How can I call C++ function with pointer struct param from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net

C++ function defined in "c++.dll"

```
FunctionName int GetDevice(VB_Device_Info* params){ do something...}

typedef struct
{
  char Name[10];
   int nPort;
}VB_Device_Info;
```

I have tried to call this function and work well in VB

```
Public Structure VB_Struc   
   Public Name As String   
   Public nPort As Integer  
End Structure
<DllImport("c++.dll")> 
Public Shared Function FunctionName(<[In](), Out()> ByVal StructArray() As VB_Struct) As Integer
End Function
```

How can I define this C++ function in C# ?

Comment: @user1810087

`Dim DeviceInfo(10) As VB_Struc `

`FunctionName(DeviceInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    struct VB_Device_Info{

       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=10)] 
       public String Name;
       int nPort; }
    [DllImport("c++.dll"]
        static extern int GetDevice(ref VB_Device_Info );`